# Cannot cons to a list in Haskell data structure

Tags: haskell

The code below has a data structure Bot which has a parameter values of type [Int]. The function giveValue retrieves the bot of a given index from a hashmap, adds a value to that bot's values parameter and returns the updated hashmap. However, it currently replaces the existing Int in values, rather than append to the array. Could someone explain to me why this is happening?

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

data Bot = Bot {values :: [Int], low :: Int, high :: Int}
instance Show (Bot) where
    show b = show (values b) ++ " " ++ show (low b) ++ " " ++ show (high b)


getBot :: Int -> Map Int (Bot)-> Bot
getBot i m
    | (length bots == 1) = bots !! 0
    | otherwise = Bot [] falseVal falseVal
    where
        falseVal = -1
        bots = [b | (i2, b) <- Map.toList m, i2==i]


giveValue :: Int -> Int -> Map Int (Bot) -> Map Int (Bot)
giveValue botInd val oldM = newM
    where
        bot = getBot val oldM
        newM = Map.insert botInd (Bot (val : values bot) (low bot) (high bot)) oldM

main = do
    let bot = Bot [17] 3 4
    let bots = Map.insert 0 bot (Map.empty)

    print $ giveValue 0 61 bots  
    -- Prints fromList [(0, [12] -1 -1)]
```

Comment: Minor style comment: `Bot (val : values bot) (low bot) (high bot)` can also be written `bot{values = val : values bot}` using the "record update" syntax.

Comment: Also, check out [`Map.update`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:update) and related functions to modify a map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean `bot = getBot botInd oldM` not `bot = getBot val oldM`.

The compiler could have caught this, except you're using `Int` as the type of both the value you want to put in and how you're looking up the bot.

Maybe if you pass in the whole `Bot` to `giveValue` instead, then you could be sure that you're giving the right value to the right bot?

You could also wrap the "bot id" in a newtype, like `newtype BotId = BotId { unBotId :: Int }`. `getBot` would take a `BotId`, and then ghc would've complained that you were passing in an integer instead of an id!

Also, consider using `Maybe Int` instead of `Int` for `low` and `high`. The fact that you're using a `falseVal` is a big red flag that you should be using `Maybe` instead.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks Libby! I'll be updating my code to use a few more subtypes, and will make sure I don't mess up like this again!